# Create a package python

Tags: python, unpack

I've created a TAR with some xml and classes, In another server i need to put those files in various directories, something like an installable, is possible?

Using CentOS

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible extract files from a tar. Can you be more specific about what your actual need is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily just have a package.format and a python script that extracts from that format and moves the files to relative locations or an absolute location if you know that. Is that what you're looking for?

You can use [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile) for the extracting/compressing and [shutil](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) and [os](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#module-os) to move/delete/modify the files.